# How to check if ComputerName is INT

Tags: c#, web-services, uwp, windows-10

I think I'm getting tired or stared at this too long.. I need a second set of eyes. If anything looks too long winded please let me know.

**My Goal**
To check the local computer name and if it's an INT to then add it to HTTPClient Request to return related values from WebService. FYI - HostName is the ID Value of this particular table. However, if the value is NOT and INT then I want to replace the actual value for a fake one so I can see my page load correctly.

Eventually, in the customer's environment, I will turn off the display of this page if the Local Computer that runs it, is not part of the correct group. That way they won't see this configuration page at all.

**Actual Results**
Because the current VM I'm running the app on does not have an INT for the name, I get the following when I put in a breakpoint to check values. But I can still go to the localhost:2463/api/devices/101070701 and see the JSON results. So I just need to get UWP to place nice so I can see it within the APP.

HostName = 0

_HostName = LOCALVM_ComputerName.

**DeviceIDService**

```
    public class DeviceIDService
{
    public static DeviceIDService Instance = new DeviceIDService();

    private DeviceIDService()
    {
        foreach (HostName DisplayName in NetworkInformation.GetHostNames())
        {
            if (DisplayName != null)
            {
                var hostNames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
                var hostName = hostNames.FirstOrDefault(name => name.Type == HostNameType.DomainName)?.DisplayName ?? "???";

                LocalName = hostName;

                break;
            }
        }
        public string LocalName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DevicePageViewModel

```
public class DevicePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Hostname = DeviceIDService.Instance.LocalName;
    public string hostName { get; set; }

    public override async OnNavigatedToAsync ()
    {
       int HostName;
        bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(_Hostname, out HostName);
        if (isNumeric == true)
        {
            HostName = 101070701;
        }
        else
        {
            string hostName = HostName.ToString();
        }

        var uriD = new Uri("http://localhost:2463/api/Devices/" + HostName);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
            var JsonResponseD = await client.GetStringAsync(uriD);
            var devicesResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Device>>(JsonResponseD);
            Devices = devicesResult;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (!isNumeric){HostName = 101070701;}` ?

Comment: I'm still kinda new to all of this... but it seems that your suggestion would change the value of ANY HostName that contains all numbers to 101070701, right? What I want it to do is, if it's a number let it pass thru, if its anything else, then change it to 101070701.

Comment: No, the suggestion would change only non-numeric values to 101070701. `int.TryParse` will return `true` if the value is numeric. Note the exclamation mark in the if statement: `if(!isNumeric)`; this is equivalent to _if isNumeric is false_. Here's a [working example](http://rextester.com/LOB83095).

Comment: ok.. I will try that.. Thanks Serge.

Comment: What if the computer name is `999999999999999`?

Comment: I'm kinda new to all of this.. and I do want to consider all scenarios that I could encounter.  However, In my customers situation, all of their computer names will contain 9 digits, 7 for location and 2 for terminal id. But since you brought it up, do you have a solution to your hypothetical, I would be glad to incorporate it to prevent issues down the road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Serge didn't actually provide an Answer but a comment. I wanted to display what he provided that solved my issue. Here is what I fixed. I changed up a few values, but this works for me..

- _Hostname - set when actual ComputerName is grabbed from pc.
- hostName  - will be set to _Hostname if it's an INT
- HostName  - will be changed to 101070701 if the actually name is NOT an INT
- HostName  - will be left alone if ComputerName is an INT

  ```
  int hostName;
  bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(_Hostname, out hostName);
  if (!isNumeric) {HostName = 101070701}
  else
  {
      HostName = hostName;
  }
  ```